# regex is ignoring special characters, but i need four digits in a row w/o special characters between

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

My goal is to find years in extracted data. I have some data that looks like "6/2009" and  "3.12.1998." I wanted to use regex to find where there are 4 digits in a row (no special characters between), but the above code returns "6200" and "3121" instead of 2009 and 1998.

```
output_year = re.findall('\d{4}', extracted_year)
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. You must be running some `re.sub(r'\W+', '', s)` before running `re.findall`

Comment: when you say that is not possible, do you mean my desired output is not possible, or the error?

Comment: Your current output is not possible to get with `re.findall('\d{4}', '3.12.1998.')`. [Try it.](https://ideone.com/N5c6f6) and you will see your code works for your input.

Comment: For clarity's sake, you might want to rename the variables, cause it doesn't make sense to extract a year from `extracted_year`. (Also Wiktor is right: your example doesn't reproduce the problem.)

Comment: Lisa, to be able to help you, you should post the whole relevant code.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew was right, there was something earlier in my code that was causing the issue. I rewrote it and it works. In the future I will post all of my code-- sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe these cases are not causing fault. For sure, add `r` before the regex pattern, like this: https://ideone.com/6XS5yE